# Jquery Conflict issue for Calendar and Quicksearch

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am using the Jquery plugins for some functionaltiy like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The above jquery i am using is for the Calendar datepicker, and the below jquery is i am using for is Quick search.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quicksearch.js"></script>
```

When I use both the Jquery library, the quciksearch functionality stops working, and Calendar Datepicker works fine. But when I remove the below plugins:-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried removing the older version of jquery for working both, but it is not working. Please help.

Comment: Is it possbile guys to make a way so that it works ?

Comment: figure a way out to use only one Jquery plugin for all functionality. check version compatibility and all. See if that works. If it doesn't then get a separate plugin for individual features. multiple Jquery versions together is not a good idea.

Comment: @VikashSingh: I already tried what you said. I used the 1.11.0 ver for all, but datepicker was not working. Need some master response to solve this.

Comment: did u use jquery-ui 1.11.0 with jquery 1.11.0 ??

Comment: No I only used `jquery 1.11.0`

Comment: Try out both js latest version together. see if they are compatible and working fine together.. let me know how it goes.

Comment: ok let me try with that.

Comment: No now both the things are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some problems with jQuery before (I had a plugin that worked only with older versions of jQuery).

The UI version your're using is probably incompatible with jQuery 1.11, check the UI site, now it's on version 1.11.12 I think. For now ignore QuickSearch plugin, update the UI and jQuery and just try to make the DatePicker work again.

In case QuickSearch doesn't work with jQuery 1.11 you can try these options:

First, you can try to add the jQuery Migrate plugin and test this again

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Case the above doesn't work, you can use the jQuery.noConflict option.

First you put the older version of jQuery and the call for its plugin:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quicksearch.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jqQuick = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    jqQuick(document).ready(function () {
        jqQuick('input#search').quicksearch('table tbody tr');
    });
</script>
```

And then you call the jQuery supposed to be used in the entire project.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So after doing this, when you need to use the older version of jQuery you're going to use `jqQuick` instead of `$` and in the rest of the project you can use `$` which is going to use jQuery 1.11 instead of 1.6.

Edit: After talking at the chat with Rahul we could check that even while using jQuery 1.11 he was still using jQuery UI for jQuery 1.6. We updated the UI to 1.11.12 and it worked fine.

Comment: didnt got u what to use when ? can you explain one by one step clearly.

Comment: First you try to update your jQuery UI, you are apparently using jQuery 1.11 with jQuery UI 1.6. If it doesn't work, you add the migrate after your jQuery 1.11 call and check if it works.

Comment: Now the way u suggested I worked, but my quick search is not working

Comment: No problems. Probably your quicksearch uses an older version of jQuery. I've edited my code above to show how to call quicksearch using jQuery 1.6, check if it works.

Comment: When you made quickserarch work, which jQuery did you have to use? 1.6 or 1.11?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66576/discussion-between-rafael-merlin-and-rahul-sutar).

Comment: Added the bounty for you, ;) Thanks and enjoy. Happy coding